# Maven and Junit

Tags: java, maven, junit, nullpointerexception

When I run a test on the ide (intelij) it works fine but when I run it on Maven it causes a nullpointerexception where a file is being created.

```
File f = new File(folder, "file");
```

It never happened before and it suddenly started happening on a class that has worked fine with it before.

I tried changing the dir and still doesnt work. Then I cleared the cache and still wont work.

Has anyone come across this before or know how to solve it?

Comment: Can you post a little more context from the code? How is dataDir being set. Are you sure it is not null?

Comment: Yes dataDir(folder) is just the folder where the file is stored. It works fine when the test is run in intelij but on maven it doesnt? I think it has something to do with the path

Comment: What are the parameters you are specifying?  Is it `(File, String)` or `(String, String)`?

Comment: If possible, please provide more context -- how is folder (nee dataDir) being initialized?

Comment: Folder is just used for the path eg samplefolder/file.txt

Answer (score 1):

I think your paths are messed up somehow. Unfortunately, you did not give enough information for us to solve the problem (there's no pom.xml, we don't know about your file structure, etc.)

However, if you put the following debug statement one line before the `new File` command, the output in both scenarios will go a long way towards tracking down the problem.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

I strongly suspect this print statement will output different things in your two scenarios. To debug this further, almost certainly you need to look at your maven pom.